# Javascript carbon counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I am trying to make a carbon savings counter that shows the steady growth of carbon savings when you open a page. I want the counter to be continuous so that the value aggregates as time goes by. I am completely new to JavaScript and have really only used HTML/CSS so I may need some hand holding on this one. Below is my code, please help!

```
var START_DATE = new Date("January, 2014 00:00:00"); // put in the starting date here
var INTERVAL = 1; // in seconds
var INCREMENT = 108.19; // increase per tick
var START_VALUE = 0; // initial value when it's the start date
var count = 0;

window.onload = function()
{
 var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
 var now = new Date();
 count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
 document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
 setInterval("count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;", msInterval);
}
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages with very different syntax and completely different libraries.

Comment: What's not working? Also, try to avoid evaluating a string in the timer.

Comment: Just so it's said, i'm enjoying the irony of spending other people's CPU cycles (=> electricity => carbon footprint) to basically brag about carbon savings.

Comment: This seems to work, not sure if its recording the right figure though -- http://jsfiddle.net/4sb7bvyr/

Comment: Are you attaching the script to the HTML or are you running it from console? Are you sure the HTML element has the ID set right? Otherwise I don't see what the problem could be, it runs with no problems for me.

Comment: @STT -- the OP got the code from here --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344940/jquery-or-javascript-continuous-counter-countup -- doesn't seem to work, at least on fiddle it doesn't :))

Comment: Hmm it works for me when I create an HTML doc and run it in the browser