# Counter with different settings for different days of the week

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a counter which will count up numbers with different increase per tick depending on day of the week. 
I found this counter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346311 which is counting the way I need but now I don't know how to make it to change INCREMENT value depending on day of the week.
Sorry for my poor english, hope question is understandable.
Regards

Thanks a lot Guys for all answers, I'm very impressed.

Comment: `new Date().getDay()` will give you the day of the week (0-6).

Comment: @RichardHamilton Thank You for Your solution this is what I'm looking for. Just one more question, can I use an array for working days if increment is the same?

Comment: One more question: Can I make this counter to count on questioned way for e.g 3 months back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `setInterval()` for this. And inside your function block, declare some conditionals, where you increment the count a different value depending on the day of the week.

To find the day of the week, use the `new Date().getDay()` method, which will return a number from 0 through 6, depending on the day.

```
var date = document.getElementById("date");

var count = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    if (new Date().getDay() === 0) {          // On Sunday's, increment by 1
        count += 1;
    }
    else if (new Date().getDay() === 1) {    // On Monday's, increment by 2
        count += 2;
    }
    else if (new Date().getDay() === 2) {    // On Tuesday's, increment by 3
        count += 3;
    }
    else if (new Date().getDay() === 3) {    // On Wednesday's, increment by 4
        count += 4;
    }
     else if (new Date().getDay() === 4) {
        count += 5;
    }
     else if (new Date().getDay() === 5) {
        count += 6;
    }
    else {
        count += 7;
    }
    date.innerHTML = count;
},1000);
```

Let me explain the above code.

I have an empty paragraph with an id equal to `date` and I'm referencing it through `document.getElementById`. I'm initializing a count variable to 0 upon page load.

At the end of my `setInterval()` loop, I'm adding the result of `count` to my div. The loop is being run once a second, which is represented by `1,000`, which is the number of milliseconds the loop should be run. You can change this to whatever you like.

I just created a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3nawhmdf/

If you want more DRY code, you could try something like this.

```
var date = document.getElementById("date");

var count = 0;

setInterval(function() {         
    count += (new Date().getDay() + 1);
    date.innerHTML = count;
},1000);
```

Credit goes to bonesbrigade for this solution

Comment: Why not opt for the concise: `count += new Date().getDay() + 1;`

Comment: Nice, can't believe I missed that one. Plus 1

Answer (score 1):

`Date.getDay()` returns the current day of the week starting at 0 (sunday)

```
var INCREMENT;     
var dayOfWeek = new Date().getDay();
switch(dayOfWeek){
   case 0: //Sunday
      INCREMENT = 2; //Add your number
      break;

   case 1: //Monday
      INCREMENT = 3; //Add your number
      break;

   //...
   case 6: //Saturday
      INCREMENT = 5; //Add your number
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do it like this

```
var daysToIncrementValues = {0: 5, 1:4, 2:3, 3:2, 4:1, 5:9, 6:7} // the values assigned are random here, you can assign whatever value
var todaysIncrementValue = dayToIncrement(new Date().getDay())
```

More concise, and no switch.

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice way of doing it, I just, wanted to make it as clear as possible. ;)

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande, Titus Popovici -  Thank You for Your answers as well.